# MYSQL Null Empty IsSet

Tags: mysql

There is a field called image_src in my table. I would like to get something like a boolean value of 1 if the field contains something ( not null or empty ) else 0 other wise. So is there any function to do that? In PHP we have isset()

Something like :

```
Select isset(image_src) from table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
SELECT if(image_src is null OR image_src = '', 0, 1) FROM table
```

This line will check if the field is null or empty.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has the [`isnull`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) function.

Comment: There is no dedicated function for that. If you want to check both, you should use a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(image_src), 0, 1) AS aliased_value FROM table
```